# Freezing on permission request Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, permissions, geolocation, task

I want to get a user's position, and therefore I'm using [James Montemagno's Geolocator Plugin for Xamarin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin). The author uses this code in the code-behind.cs file; I extracted it to a static class:

```
public static class GeoService
{
    public static Position savedPosition;

    public static async Task<Position> GetPosition()
    {
        var lastknown = await ExecuteLastKnownPosition();

        if(lastknown == null)
        {
            var current = await ExecuteGPSPosition();
            if(current != null)
            {
                return current;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return lastknown;
    }

    private static async Task<Position> ExecuteLastKnownPosition()
    {
        try

        {

            var hasPermission = await Utils.CheckPermissions(Permission.Location);

            if (!hasPermission)

                return null;

            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

            //Progress Ring einfügen

            var position = await locator.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();

            if (position == null)
            {
                //Benachrichtigung über null lastknownLocation
                //Aufrufen der CurrentPosition Methode
                return null;
            }

            savedPosition = position;
            return position;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Uh oh", "Something went wrong, but don't worry we captured for analysis! Thanks.", "OK");
            return null;
        }

        finally
        {
            //Freigabe der Buttons und Bools
        }


    }

    private static async Task<Position> ExecuteGPSPosition()

    {

        try

        {

            var hasPermission = await Utils.CheckPermissions(Permission.Location);

            if (!hasPermission)

                return null;


            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 100;

            //WarteText/Symbol

            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));

            if (position == null)

            {
                //Warnung, dass kein GPS vorhanden ist
                return null;
            }

            savedPosition = position;
            return position;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Uh oh", "Something went wrong, but don't worry we captured for analysis! Thanks.", "OK");
            return null;
        }

        finally

        {
            //Zurücksetzen von Buttons und Lademodus beenden
        }

    }

    public static async Task<Address> ExecuteTrackingAdress(Position currentPosition)

    {

        try
        {

            //if (savedPosition == null)
            //    return null;

            var hasPermission = await Utils.CheckPermissions(Permission.Location);
            if (!hasPermission)
                return null;

            string mapkey = "Ajbb9XXXXXXatUzUg1w9BSXXXXXVUAEuF4P-TSXJpnvl5OpXXXXXXXXX";
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

            var addresses = await locator.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(currentPosition, mapkey);
            var address = addresses.FirstOrDefault();
            if (address == null)

            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Keine Adresse vorhanden");
            }

            return address;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        {

            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Uh oh", "Something went wrong, but don't worry we captured for analysis! Thanks.", "OK");
            return null;
        }

        finally

        {

        }

    }
}
```

Now I got a ContentPage, and when I go to that page (PushModalAsync) the constructor in the view model calls the `GetPosition()` method. There's a permission Task and whenever the Task is running, UWP offers me to prompt the location permission.

Unfortunately, from this point on the app is freezing. I can't choose Yes/No, and there's no way of interaction.

I tried to call the methods async, with `Task.WhenAll()` and so on, but it freezes every time.

This was the last code I wrote in my view model

```
 private async void ExecuteGetPosition()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        await Task.Yield();
        var positiontask = GeoService.GetPosition();
        var addresstask = GeoService.ExecuteTrackingAdress(positiontask.Result);
        await Task.WhenAll(positiontask, addresstask);
        CurrentPosition = positiontask.Result;
        CurrentAddress = addresstask.Result;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentAddressView");
        IsBusy = false;

    }
```

I'm assuming that the XAML ContentPage isn't already loaded correctly, and so the prompting-window slips "behind" the MainWindow or something.

Please could you give me an idea for a workaround to handle this?

**Edit:**
Adding these lines to my App.xaml.cs OnStart()-Method brought the solution. Windows is now calling for permission OnStart, Android asks for permission on gps-request...crazy:

```
var permission = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
```

Comment: Could you try awaiting all the way up to the source caller before pushing the page or within your new page's `OnAppearing` method so you will not have to mess with all of the `Task` methods? Just to see if it prevents the freezing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on iOS? If so, look at the simulator's console log to see if there is a privacy error. I am guessing it has to do with the privacy declarations required to be in the info.plist when requesting location permissions.

Check out all of the required privacy declarations listed [here](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/GettingStarted.html#iostvosmacos).

They include (check out the link for info on when to add each one):

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access location when open.</string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access location when in the background.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access location when open and in the background.</string>
```

Comment: Hey hvaughan3, thank you for your advice. I'm running this on windows and it seems to be a problem with async operations, so the mainthread is busy or does anything I don't expect. On Android everything works fine. See my edited question.